# Unsupported Configuration,Sample rate 11025, format 1,ChannelMask 0x10

Tags: android, audio, recorder

I am implementing Audio Recorder in my application. It worked fine for a few days but it now shows the error `Unsupported Configuration,Sample rate 11025, format 1,ChannelMask 0x10.`

This is my logcat:

```
 12-17 09:04:26.325: E/AudioRecord(1195): Unsupported configuration: sampleRate 11025, format 1, channelMask 0x10
 12-17 09:04:26.335: W/dalvikvm(1195): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
 12-17 09:04:26.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1195): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-117
 12-17 09:04:26.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1195): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2
 12-17 09:04:26.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):    at com.example.sms.OtherActivity.startRecord(OtherActivity.java:196)
 12-17 09:04:26.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):    at com.example.sms.OtherActivity.access$5(OtherActivity.java:180)
 12-17 09:04:26.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):    at com.example.sms.OtherActivity$1$1.run(OtherActivity.java:142)
 12-17 09:04:26.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is my code for implementing audio record,

```
 private void startRecord()
            { 
                  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

                  try
                  {
                        file.createNewFile();

                        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
                        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

                        int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

                        short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

                        AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                    11025,
                                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                    minBufferSize);

                        audioRecord.startRecording();

                        while(recording)
                        {
                              int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                              for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++)
                              {
                                    dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                              }
                        }
                        audioRecord.stop();
                        dataOutputStream.close();

                  }
                  catch (IOException e)
                  {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }

            }

            void playRecord()
            {
                  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

                  int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

                  int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);
                  short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

                  try {
                        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

                        int i = 0;
                        while(dataInputStream.available() > 0)
                        {
                              audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                              i++;
                        }

                        dataInputStream.close();

                        AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                    11025,
                                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                    bufferSizeInBytes,
                                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                        audioTrack.play();
                        audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);


                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                  {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e)
                  {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }



            }
```

What is causing this error and how can I rectify it?

Comment: Please include relevant parts of your code, e.g. `startRecord()`

Comment: Try using `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` as the format, and 8000, 16000, 44100 or 48000 as the sample rate.

Comment: @laalto I have pasted the startRecord and playrecord() method in my question

Comment: The exception is because `getMinBufferSize()` returns a negative number because of the error (hw does not support the params given), and you try to allocate `audioData` with negative number of elements. 44100Hz is the only sampling rate that is guaranteed to work on all devices.

Comment: @laalto I changed sampling rate from 11025 to 44100 but it shows same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing invalid (unsupported) params to `getMinBufferSize()` and it returns -2 `ERROR_BAD_VALUE`. Attempting to allocate negative number of elements for an array causes the `NegativeArraySizeException`.

Now, [`CHANNEL_CONFIGRATION_MONO`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat.html#CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO) has been deprecated for a long time. You should use `CHANNEL_IN_MONO` instead. That's the likely cause for the `ERROR_BAD_VALUE`.

Comment: yeah I cleared that error but it now shows could not get audio input for record source error